# php array_diff not working on this compare

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have two arrays:

```
(
    [lineCode] => C
    [serviceRequest] => Ext, Warr auth.#19091100102 for $650.64 to be paid by c/card(fax#817-785-6700). Cust owes balance
    [skillCode] => 90SB
    [opCode] => 90SB
    [jobType] => CUSTOMER
    [techNo] => 
    [lineStatus] => C
)
```

```
(
    [id] => 755350
    [rid] => 252178
    [lineCode] => C
    [serviceRequest] => Ext, Warr auth.#19091100102 for $650.64 to be paid by c/card(fax#817-785-6700). Cust owes balance
    [skillCode] => 90SB
    [opCode] => 90SB
    [jobType] => CUSTOMER
    [techNo] => 
    [lineStatus] => W
    [timeA] => 1575497139
    [timeC] => 0
)
```

When i perform `$diff = array_diff($arry1, $arry2);`, it does not find the `lineStatus` to be different. Could it be because of service Request line with special characters? Although as a test, I set both lines to blanks, and it still did not see the difference.

Any help would be great. Stumped for the day.

**UPDATE w/ MORE INFO**
As this is part of a larger loop through mulitple arrays, the diff check before this one above is below:

```
$arry1= Array
(
    [lineCode] => B
    [serviceRequest] => 
    [skillCode] => 15
    [opCode] => 15
    [jobType] => CUSTOMER
    [techNo] => A05
    [lineStatus] => C
)
$arry2= Array
(
    [id] => 755362
    [rid] => 252184
    [lineCode] => B
    [serviceRequest] => 
    [skillCode] => 15
    [opCode] => 15
    [jobType] => CUSTOMER
    [techNo] => A05
    [lineStatus] => W
    [timeA] => 1575504138
    [timeC] => 0
)
$diff= Array
(
    [lineStatus] => C
)
```

the code for the diff is `$diff=array_diff($arry1,$arry2);`

If it works correctly for this one, why would it not for the next.

Comment: What is the output of `$diff`?

Comment: switch your arrays inside `array_diff()`, i.e. `$diff = array_diff($arry2, $arry1);`

Comment: I switched them and it found the difference. But why does it not find it the way I original did it?

Comment: $diff= array(); it come back blank.

Comment: If you read the description of this function in the manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), then you would know why it works like that!

**Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.**

The field "lineStatus" doesn't exists in your first array, therefore it is not recognized  as a difference to your second array where this field exists cause all fields of your first array exists also in your second array.

Comment: @CodyKL - lineStatus is defined in both ... (last item on array1 ... 3rd from bottom in the second)

Comment: @CodyKL is a little confused, the reason you're getting an empty array with `$diff = array_diff($arry1, $arry2);` is because all **values** found in `$arry1` also exist in `$arry2`. But not the other way around... thus if you reverse the argument arrays to `$diff = array_diff($arry2, $arry1);`, you will get a results array with differences, i.e. all the elements with **values** that exist in `$arry2` and not in `$arry1`.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it not find it the way you originally did it...?

`array_diff()` does not care about key-value combinations, it only compares the **values** in the different arrays that are compared.

To better understand what's happening: if in your updated data you introduce an array element `[dummy] => "C"` into `$arry2` you will no longer get `[lineStatus] => "C"` returned into `$diff`. As the value `C` is now found in both `$arry1` and `$arry2`.

Have a look at this [demo](https://3v4l.org/qoN2t)

Comment: lineStatus exists in both though. There is a lineCode and lineStatus is both. (last item on array1 ... 3rd from bottom in the second)

Comment: Yes, but a value `W` only exists in `$arry2`, hence it returns `["lineStatus"]=>
  string(1) "W"` - again, the keys (or key-value combinations) are inconsequential, the function only cares about the values.

Comment: `arry1` has ['lineStatus']=C ... `arry2` has ['lineStatus']=W || I have tested this with other arrays and it works correctly, only in this case is it not seeing the difference. - will post another example

Comment: Put it differently, if in your updated data you introduce an array element `[dummy] => "C"` into `$arry2` you will no longer get `[lineStatus] => "C"` returned into `$diff`. As the value `C` is now found in both `$arry1` and `$arry2` - have a look at this [demo](https://3v4l.org/qoN2t)

Comment: Awesome. array_diff uses array_flip. Thanks. if you want to create this as a standalone answer, I will happy give credit!

Comment: happy I could help!